# Random background-image not loading sometimes on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, background-image

I have a website with several "background-image: url('');" css rules. All works perfectly on Chrome and Safari but on Firefox some of these images don't load the image, just the correct size(randomly).

[image: checkerboard is dispalyed in devtools]

I refresh (cleaning the cache) and some of them loads and some not, always different. Checking the network traffic all loads without problems (200) but looking at the images in the inspector it appears with correct size but empty.

I found that if I switch to another browser tab and back, all is loaded correctly. Scrolling doesn't make any new image loads, changing the source of the background image neither, some CSS changes make some image loads, like switching position absolute-relative. Happening with jpg and png images.

Firefox 68.0.2
Firefox Developer edition 69.0.b12-13

Have been trying things for hours but no luck. 
Thank you very much for any help to debug the issue in advance.

Comment: You gonna have to show an example of something, it's hard to say why based on a description alone

Comment: It is a dev site but will try to replicate it in a way I can share, thanks.

Comment: Not having luck replicating it but found that enabling and disabling display:inline-flex in the elements with background-image loads the missing images if it helps.

Comment: You can probably figure out what's going when you inspect. Maybe your display is putting the image offscreen or maybe there is no content in the elements so the element is not showing. But when you inspect, it will highlight the item so if you don't see the highlight then something is off

Comment: I see the highlight correctly but are elements with no content, just the background-image. Will try to add some content to see how it works, thank you!

Comment: Firefox decodes images "as needed" (when they become visible) to save RAM, and it sounds like the visibility check failed. If you manage to produce a minimized testcase, please share - so that it could be reported to Mozilla.

Comment: Thanks, Nickolay. I tried to replicate it without too much luck but will try to create a new page to replicate the issue in a few days.